# Filter Vector Layer Features

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, java

I'm using OpenLayers - 2.11,GeoServer 2.13, ExtJS 3.4, and Java for developing GIS based web applications.

I have added some point features in one vector layer.
It has id, name, address, etc.

Can I filter some points with 'name' from that vector layer and only show matched features in vector layer?
I have to filter some points and later I have to show all hidden data.

eg: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already setup the stylemaps for diplaying labels. You can easily do this by checking the feature attribute value of the required field with the search text

Try the below code to search in attributes

```
//JS code
    function search() {
    var search_name = document.getElementById("search_text").value;
    var features = layer.features;
    layer.destroyFeatures();
    for(var i=0; i< features.length; i++) {

     //features[i].attributes.name. you have the attribute field "name"

      if(features[i].attributes.name === search_name) {
        layer.addFeatures([features[i]])
      }
    }

    layer.redraw();
    }

<!-- HTML stuff  -->
    <input type="text" id="search_text" />
    <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
```

**Update:**
hide/show using renderIntent

```
    //JS code

        function search() {
        var search_name = document.getElementById("search_text").value;
        var features = layer.features;
        for(var i=0; i< features.length; i++) {

         //features[i].attributes.name. you have the attribute field "name"

         //hide  a feature by default
          features[i].renderIntent = "delete"; 
          if(features[i].attributes.name === search_name) {
           //show a feature value of name attribute is search_name 
            features[i].renderIntent = "default" 
          }
        }

        layer.redraw();
        }
```

The second method becomes faster as `renderIntent="delete"` will set the css property `display: none;`(hiding) and `renderIntent="default"` will use the default rendering from your stylemap obivously showing the features.

Comment: Dear rashad.. thank you for the reply.. but, i can't add features in vector layer. i think instead of layer.addFeatures([feature]) i can use layer.removeFeatures([feature])....Can i hide / filter some features from vector layer? and later can i show all the previous feature.

Comment: @RamRamesh. I added another alternative which is more apt for you. hide/show instead of remove and add again.